# Can't get madlib.forest_train() in Rstudio by using PivotalR library

Tags: r, rstudio, random-forest, greenplum, madlib

I have configured RStudio to run R code natively on Greenplum. I have searched online but I couldn't find answer to the problem I am facing at the moment.

I have imported the `library(PivotalR)` and `library(RPostgreSQL)`. But, when I type `madlib` it just comes up with few of the functions:

[image]

The Greenplum database has also been configured with Madlib functions including `madlib.forest_train`, which does not show up in RStudio. I am assuming it has something to do with the PivotalR package for RStudio. Is there a way to make the `forest_train` work directly from RStudio?